# vimeo plays count using player.js

Tags: javascript, vimeo

how to get number of plays for specific video??
For now i using player.js but i can't find that option in documentation.
anyone know how to do it? with or without player.js?

my code starts like that :

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
```

when i need to call some funtion i do like that

```
function CurrentTime(e){
  player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
    seconds = Math.floor(seconds);
    post_data = { $result : seconds , $title : e};   
      $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: post_data,
        url: '../includes/php/send_user_video.php',
          success: function (data) {
          }
        });
  }).catch(function(error) {console.log(error)});
}
```

I need that number to be displayed as well as video.
[image]

repository - [github](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/)

Answer (score 0):

The total play stat is not retrievable using the Player API. Instead, use the Vimeo API to get a video's metadata (including the total play stat, if the video owner has not hidden it). More information here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224982748-How-do-I-hide-my-video-stats-from-viewers-